# How to write one piece of code to add innerHTML to an element for different options

Tags: javascript

I am trying to fetch some info from an api where it gives name, authorname, publisher and firstpublish year of book. but sometimes the firstpublish year is missing. I want to show this informations in a page. I am writing these piece of code ---

```
const searchResultShow = data => {
    parentDiv = document.getElementById('result-details');
    parentDiv.innerText = "";
    data.docs.forEach(key=>{
        bookName = key.title;
        authorname = key.author_name[0];
        publisher = key.publisher[0]; 
        newElem = document.createElement('div')
        newElem.classList.add('col')
        if ('first_publish_year' in key){
            firstPublish = key.first_publish_year;
            newElem.innerHTML = `
            <h4>Name: ${bookName}</h3>
            <h4>Author Name: ${authorname}</h4>
            <h4>Publisher: ${publisher}</h4>
            <h4>First Publish Year: ${firstPublish}</h4>
            `
        }
        else {
            newElem.innerHTML = `
            <h4>Name: ${bookName}</h3>
            <h4>Author Name: ${authorname}</h4>
            <h4>Publisher: ${publisher}</h4>
            `
        }
        parentDiv.appendChild(newElem);
    })
```

As you can see this is not efficient, I am writing newElem.innerHTML twice. And if some other parameters are missing, I have to repeat this again and again. What could be an easy solution to get rid of this repeating situation?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because IMO Stack Exchange : Code Review would be the proper site for this question

Comment: Just be aware that questions asking for an alternative solution to a problem you have solved are often opinion based, and better suited to Code Review on the Stack Exchange

Comment: @ControlAltDel "questions asking for an alternative solution" are off-topic on Code Review. Please do not use another site as a reason to close questions, so users aren't stuck between sites. If the question is off-topic on Stack Overflow then say why the question is off-topic. "fits better" isn't a reason.

Comment: @Peilonrayz I am confused about your recommendation here. I created a chat room where I hoped you and/or others might be able to 
help me better understand how to handle questions such as this. I am hoping you will join and discuss/enlighten me?: (https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236695/discussions-on-requests-for-help-finding-a-better-solution)

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is probably to separate out the lines, then combine them:

```
const firstPublishHTML = ('first_publish_year' in key) ? `<h4>First Publish Year: ${key.first_publish_year}</h4>` : ''
...

newElem.innerHTML = `<h4>Name: ${bookName}</h4>
...
${firstPublishHTML}...`
```

Basically, if the element is present, your variable is a valid HTML line, if it's not, it's an empty string

Answer (score 1):

Typically for this sort of thing I would try and use a null check that resides in-line instead of a wrapping if statement. That'll keep it DRY and let you add a function to resolve the data later if you ever get that option. In this way you can keep tacking conditionals onto your template and slowly build it out.

```
const searchResultShow = data => {
    parentDiv = document.getElementById('result-details');
    parentDiv.innerText = "";
    data.docs.forEach(key=>{
        bookName = key.title;
        authorname = key.author_name[0];
        publisher = key.publisher[0]; 
        newElem = document.createElement('div')
        newElem.classList.add('col')
        newElem.innerHTML = `
        <h4>Name: ${bookName}</h3>
        <h4>Author Name: ${authorname}</h4>
        <h4>Publisher: ${publisher}</h4>
        `
        newElem.innerHTML += (('first_publish_year' in key) ? `<h4>First Publish Year: ${key.first_publish_year}</h4>` : ``);
        }
        parentDiv.appendChild(newElem);
    })
```

Alternatively, since this is going to be parsed, you can have a string that you build onto, and then make a single call to innerHTML with that string:

```
const searchResultShow = data => {
    parentDiv = document.getElementById('result-details');
    parentDiv.innerText = "";
    data.docs.forEach(key=>{
        let innerHTMLString = "";
        bookName = key.title;
        authorname = key.author_name[0];
        publisher = key.publisher[0]; 
        newElem = document.createElement('div')
        newElem.classList.add('col')
        innerHTMLString += `
        <h4>Name: ${bookName}</h3>
        <h4>Author Name: ${authorname}</h4>
        <h4>Publisher: ${publisher}</h4>
        `
        innerHTMLString += (('first_publish_year' in key) ? `<h4>First Publish Year: ${key.first_publish_year}</h4>` : ``);
        newElem.innerHTML(innerHTMLString);
        }
        parentDiv.appendChild(newElem);
    })
```

Making it marginally more efficient not having to call innerHTML twice. This is a better technique as your code gets more evolved and you may be performing numerous calls to the innerHTML function.

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding/concatenating strings like this:

Since this looks like it won't be changed part of code:

```
`newElem.innerHTML` = 
        
<h4>Name: ${bookName}</h3>
<h4>Author Name: ${authorname}</h4>
<h4>Publisher: ${publisher}</h4>
```

You can do like following:

```
        newElem.innerHTML = `
            <h4>Name: ${bookName}</h3>
            <h4>Author Name: ${authorname}</h4>
            <h4>Publisher: ${publisher}</h4>
            `
        if ('first_publish_year' in key){
            firstPublish = key.first_publish_year;
            newElem.innerHTML += `<h4>First Publish Year: ${firstPublish}</h4>`
        }
```